# Idea for determining which node to delete

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml, dom

My site's homepage displays all the details of the movies i have in an xml file(performed with a `foreach` PHP loop,and DOM),i want to add a delete button now for each movie,so that should be done within the loop,the problem is i know how to delete the xml node,given the movie title,but,i can't find a way to transfer the data(movie title) to the page where i could confirm the deletion,i tried some solutions that didnt work:

-I tried a `<form method="post" action="foobar">` within the PHP loop,with an `<input type="hidden"name="deletion" value="php code giving the movie title">` but as you can see it gives the same name each time the loop runs again,so it obviously will not work.

-Thought about using buttons instead of forms within loop,with onClick event funstions,but i don't want to include js in this at all

-I looked for solutions on forums,i found cookies,sessions,array names...i don't want to use those either,because they aren't effective,since i can't determine which movie title was transfered(because i don't even know the name of the variable that contains it)

Is there any other solution for this problem?would be great
PS:i am coding by hand,a friend already told me,that if i was using a framework,it would have been very easy,but i want to learn to code by hand first,then framework.

I can of course provide with code if necessary.

```
    foreach($Movies as $Movie) { ?>
    <div class="iodata">
    <?php echo "Movie : {$Movie->Title}<br /><br />";
    echo "Genre : {$Movie->Genre}<br /><br />";
    echo "Year : {$Movie->Year}<br /><br />";
    echo "Actors : {$Movie->Cast}<br /><br />";
    echo "Director : {$Movie->Director}<br /><br>";
    echo "Synopsis : {$Movie->Synopsis}<br /><br />";?>
    <form method="post" action="confirm.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="deletion" value="<?php echo "$Movie->Title";?>">
    <input type="submit" value="delete this">
    </form>
    </div><br>
    <?php }}?>
```

Comment: Can you add the code for your first attempt, with the for-loop and the `<form method="post">`? That should work just fine - it's probably something small.

Comment: @Kenney it can't be,by logic,because all the forms have the same input name,and in the other page where the action goes,i tried to `echo`  the `$_POST['deletion']` it says,deletion undefined index.

Comment: Thanks. You'll need `<form method='post' action='confirm.php'>` - the default is `get`, which puts `deletion` in `$_GET`. You could also use `$_REQUEST`, and then it doesn't matter if it's POST or GET.

Comment: @kenny that actually was a test page code,in the main one i have put the `method="post"` which is why i mentionned it didnt work,my bad i will edit the post,but still doesnt solve anything though.

Comment: Ok, now, if you put this in your `confirm.php`, you'll see that `deletion` has a different value depending on which submit button you click: `echo "<pre>" . print_r( $_POST, 1 ) . "</pre>";`

Comment: i did that this way,it is basically the same thing `$x=$_POST['deletion'];
 echo " $x ";   `but it doesn't work,i tried yours,doesn't work either

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not an answer, but this doesn't fit in the comments.

Try these files, and see if they work for you:

**movies.php**

```
<?php

  $Movies = [
     (object) [ 'Title' => 'Foo', 'Genre' => 'Action' ],
     (object) [ 'Title' => 'Bar', 'Genre' => 'Drama' ],
  ];

  foreach($Movies as $Movie) { ?>
    <div class="iodata">
    <?php echo "Movie : {$Movie->Title}<br /><br />";
    echo "Genre : {$Movie->Genre}<br /><br />";
    echo "Year : {$Movie->Year}<br /><br />";
    echo "Actors : {$Movie->Cast}<br /><br />";
    echo "Director : {$Movie->Director}<br /><br>";
    echo "Synopsis : {$Movie->Synopsis}<br /><br />";?>
    <form method="post" action="confirm.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="deletion" value="<?php echo "$Movie->Title";?>">
    <input type="submit" value="delete this">
    </form>
    </div><br>
    <?php
  }
```

**confirm.php**

```
<?php

    echo "<pre>" . print_r( $_REQUEST, 1 ) . "</pre>";
```

If you click the first button, you should see

```
Array
(
    [deletion] => Foo
)
```

Comment: they actually doesn't work either,the data is not being sent to the confirm page,at all,that is the problem

Comment: So, you pasted the first snipped in a file called 'movies.php', the second snippet in a file called 'confirm.php', then requested the first file through your webserver, clicked a button, and nothing happens? I tested it: [see here](http://neonics.com/test2/movies.php) - these are the exact same files.